# can't install buddypress on my shared hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, installation, buddypress

I have a problem regarding buddypress installation. I can not install buddypress on my shared hosting server. The server giving an "Internal serever error 500" , when i tried to access the website after activated buddypress plugin. The admin panel is also not working.
But it is working properly on my local server (wamp)
The version of wordpress and buddypress I have used are
Wordpress : 3.3.1
Buddypress : 1.5.4

Could any one suggest a solution. I can not move a bit with my new project if the problem not solved
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP error log?

Comment: can you access your error logs? It could be that mod_rewrite or any other expected module is not enabled by your shared host

Comment: make sure .htaccess file exists and valid

Comment: Also need to make sure your PHP & MySQL versions are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would look for if you don't have access to your error_log. .htaccess file is in place and directory permissions.